# How to link between menu and main file in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, menu

For example I have two files:

1. main.py
2. menu.py

`main` contains the game and `menu` contains a play button which to click to start the game.

I want to link between these two files for whenever I press play button the `main` starts to run without creating a new window.

I tried this:

```
main.py > running = False
          while running:
              (main.py works)

menu.py > from main import *
          if click:
              running = True
```

but it didn't worked for some reason..

Would you consider helping me out?

Comment: Add a function to "menu.py". Return "running" from the function. Call the function in "manu.py"

Comment: what means `didnt worked` ? Did you get error message? Put FULL error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image).

Comment: better put code in fuctions - like `def mainloop(): ...` -  so you can `import main` and use `if click: main.mainloop()`. You could also create `screen` (and other objects) only in first file and send them as arguments - i.e `main.mainloop(screen)`. To make it simpler you can keep all values in dictionary like `config = {"screen": screen, ...}` and later send `main.mainloop(config)`

Comment: BTW: if you have all code directly in file `main.py` and you do `from main import *` then it runs all this code from `main` at once so it may not works as you expect - it may block code in `menu` and it will not work - and you can't control when it will be executed. Besides `import` loads code only once and you will try to run again `import` it will not load it again.

Answer (score 1):

You should put code in functions so later you can run `main.run(screen)` to run game.

---

Minimal working example.

First it runs `menu` with red screen and when you click then it uses `main.run(screen)` to run `main` with green screen. When you click again then it uses `return` to go back to `menu`.

`menu.py`

```
import pygame
import main

def run(screen=None):
    print('[menu] run')

    if not screen:
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    mainloop(screen)

def mainloop(screen):
    print('[menu] mainloop')

    running = True
    while running:

        print('running menu ...')

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit() # skip rest of code
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    main.run(screen)  # run game

        screen.fill((255,0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

`main.py`

```
import pygame


def run(screen=None):
    print('[main] run')

    if not screen:
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    mainloop(screen)

def mainloop(screen):
    print('[main] mainloop')

    running = True
    while running:

        print('running game ...')

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit() # skip rest of code
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    return  # go back to menu

        screen.fill((0,255,0))
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

As you can see both code can be very similar. You could use the same code to create window with `settings.py`, `results.py`, etc. This way code can be simpler and later you can reuse some elements using classes.

To make it even more usefull you could dictionary `config = {'screen': screen, ...}` and send it to `main.run(config)`, `settings.run(config)`, `results.run(config)` and send it back with `return config`